# The order of using "this" for object references

Tags: html, oop, dom, object

In a JavaScript Guide on MDN I've found an example

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label>Form name:<input type="text" name="text1" value="Beluga"></label>
  <input name="button1" type="button" value="Show Form Name"
     onclick="this.form.text1.value = this.form.name">
</form>
```

When we click `<input>` we have this strange inverse reference to it's parent (`this.form...`). It seems strange for me as I've always seen using object reference in an 'ordered' way. How can an object's property (input of form's node) refer to it's object in this way (`this.form`)? Or am I confusing Object oriented programming with DOM model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that because `this` within the event handler refers to the DOM element ([`HTMLInputElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlinputelement)) for the button, and those DOM elements have a property, [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-fae-form), that refers to the form they're in (if they're in one). It's just how the DOM is defined. (Don't let those links fool you, this isn't a new HTML5 thing; it's been this way for ages: [Older `HTMLInputElement` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025).)

In tree structures (DOM and otherwise), it's not uncommon for the leaf nodes to have a reference to their parent (since in a tree, they can only have one parent). This is just an extension of that concept.